# Problem Books in Algebraic Topology/Differential Topology (with solutions)

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

For Differential Geometry there's this wonderful book called *"Analysis and Algebra on DIfferentiable Manifolds"*, which is a big problem book containing problems (and solutions).

For a self-studying student this is particularly helpful because these sorts of books provide us with a good feedback loop. If we attempt a problem, get stuck on and can't solve it, we can always read the first few lines of a solution to see a hint on where to go next, and if we are *really* stuck we can check the full solution.

Do such books exist for Algebraic Topology, or Differential Topology? Or is the best method to gain a similar sort of feedback loop to read the theorems and examples in a book like Hatcher or Guillemin and Pollack and attempt to prove the theorems and examples by hand?

Comment: "Or is the best method to gain a similar sort of feedback loop to read the theorems and examples in a book like Hatcher or Guillemin and Pollack and attempt to prove the theorems and examples by hand?" or use google or this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check [Elementary topology problem textbook](http://www.pdmi.ras.ru/~olegviro/topoman/eng-book-nopfs.pdf), freely available in the English noproof version. An English 2nd ed. with proofs is for sale, but the first ed. (with proofs) is also freely available [here](https://www.math.kth.se/math/GRU/2008.2009/SF2721/) (toward the bottom).

Part 2 deals with algebraic topology